# Как переформатировать текст средствами bash?

Tags: bash

Добрый день, есть файл с таким содержимым:

```
name1
PoweredOff
192.168.250.31
Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)
Other 2.6.x Linux (64-bit)

name2
PoweredOn
192.168.250.99
Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)
Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)
```

Нужно привести его к виду:

```
|name1|PoweredOff|192.168.250.31|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 2.6.x Linux 64-bit)|
|name2|PoweredOn|192.168.250.99|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)|
```

Пытался делать подобное:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat file); do if [[ -n $i ]]; then tr -s '\n' ' '; fi; done
```

но это не работает

Comment: записи отделены пустой строкой?

Comment: Не надо использовать `bash` для этого! Помимо того, что `for i in $(cat file)` -- это неверно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При помощи awk:

```
awk -vRS='' -vFS='\n' -vOFS='|' '{$1=$1;print "",$0,""}' < data.txt
```

Переменная RS задает разделитель между записями (пустая строка), FS - разделитель полей внутри записи (перевод строки). Любая команда, изменяющая любое поле (в данном случае `$1=$1`) неявно пересобирает запись (`$0`), используя в качестве разделителя значение OFS.

**UPD**: изменил для произвольного числа строк в записи.

Comment: Это не `bash`, а `awk`.

Comment: @0andriy awk входит в стандарт posix, сталобыть присутствует в любом шелле, его поддерживающем, коим является bash. Собственно awk можно смело считать его нативной командой.

Comment: Увы, но строго говоря нет. `#!/bin/awk` и поехали. Это будет честно. Правильный ответ дал @avp.

Answer (score 3):

средствами программы *bash* это будет довольно затруднительно, хотя и возможно.

гораздо проще вопспользоваться более подходящими программами: awk, sed и т.п.

пример для программы *awk* уже дали. вот пример для программы *sed*:

```
$ sed '/^$/d;N;N;N;N;s/\n/|/g;s/^/|/;s/$/|/' файл
```

результат:

```
|name1|PoweredOff|192.168.250.31|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 2.6.x Linux (64-bit)|
|name2|PoweredOn|192.168.250.99|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)|
```

---

**обновление**

если количество строк в блоках текста, разделённых пустой строкой, постоянное, то вышеприведённую программу для интерпретатора *sed* можно подстраивать, изменяя количество операторов `N;`.

если же количество строк переменное, то программу придётся немного усложнить (тут, вероятно, много лишнего, и можно соптимизировать):

```
$ sed '/^$/d;:a;$!N;s/\n$/|/;tb;s/\n/|/;ta;:b;s/^/|/;$s/$/|/' файл
```

когда файл содержит такие строки:

```
name1
PoweredOff
192.168.250.31
Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)

name2
PoweredOn
192.168.250.99
```

то вывод программы будет такой:

```
|name1|PoweredOff|192.168.250.31|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|
|name2|PoweredOn|192.168.250.99|
```

Comment: Жестко привязно к формату 5 строк в одном блоке

Comment: @avp, и строго говоря, это `sed`, а не `bash`. (`#!/bin/sed -f`...)

Comment: @avp, во-первых, не привязано к «формату 5 строк в одном блоке», и, тем более, «жёстко» — это легко изменяется количеством операторов `N;`. во-вторых, раз уж зашла такая пьянка, дополнил вариантом для переменного количества строк в блоке.

Comment: Супер, но с несколькими пустыми строками перед блоком сбивается.

Comment: @avp, чтоб вы были спокойны, добавил ещё одну проверку. на этом предлагаю прекратить фантазировать по поводу того, какой же на самом деле у автора файл.

Comment: Теперь наверное работает. Проблема с подобными скриптами в том, что 1) никогда не уверен в нем и 2) он абсолютно не понятен и поэтому не модифицируем.  / Вспоминается какая-то история про программу на языке APL из 5 строк, которую один из авторов языка "декодировал" 5 часов.

Comment: @avp, ладно уж придираться. я ж молчу про то, что предложенное вами решение «съедает» все начальные/конечные пробельные символы в строках. и если уж речь зашла про анекдотические истории, то мне вот очень нравится та, что кончается словами «да вы их просто готовить не умеете!». там речь про кошек, конечно, а не про sed.

Comment: А как надо делать, чтобы не съедало? (я обычно просто на Си пишу подобные штуки)

Answer (score 3):

На bash, как-то так:

```
#!/bin/bash

out=""
while read s
do
    if [ "$s" = "" ]; then
        [ "$out" = "" ] || echo "$out|"
        out=""
    else
        out="$out|$s"
    fi
done
[ "$out" = "" ] || echo "$out|"
```

Несколько пустых строк считает за одну, а также не зависит от числа строк в блоке (параграфе).

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ ./tt.sh <tt.txt
|name1|PoweredOff|192.168.250.31|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 2.6.x Linux (64-bit)|
|name2|PoweredOn|192.168.250.99|Debian GNU/Linux 6 (64-bit)|Other 3.x Linux (64-bit)|
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

Для использования в другом скрипте, возможно, лучше оформить как функцию.

Comment: А также не забываем о ключевом слове `local` при использовании в виде функции.